# The dual of $L^1(X)$ is no isomorphic to $L^\infty$ for measures that are not $\sigma$-finite.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite meausure space. For each fixed $f\in L^\infty(X)$, we consider the functional $F$ defined as follows $$\large F(g)=\int_X fg\;d\mu,\quad g\in L^1(X).$$ It is easy to prove that $F\in\left(L^1(X)\right)^*$.

We know that the map $$\Large i\colon L^{\infty}(X)\to \left(L^1(X)\right)^*,\quad f \mapsto i(f):=F$$ is an isometry and surjective (From Riesz-Fischer Theorem). Therefore if $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure, then the dual of $L^1(X)$ is isomorphic to $L^\infty(X)$.

I want to see that if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite, then what has just been said is false. For this purpose we consider the following exercise:

Let $X=[0,1]$, $\mathcal{A}=\{E\subseteq [0,1]\; |\; E\;\text{or}\; E^c\;\text{is countable}\}$, $\nu=\text{"Cardinality Measure"}$.

> $(i)$ For all $f\in L^1(X)$ the function $x\mapsto xf(x)$ is in $L^1(X)$

**Proof $(i)$**

We have that $$\lVert xf \rVert _1=\int_0^1 \lvert xf(x) \rvert\;d\nu\le\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert\;d\nu<\infty$$

> $(ii)$ the functionl $F$, defined by $F(f)=\int_0^1 xf(x)\;d\nu$ for all $f\in L^1(X)$, is in $\left (L^1(X) \right)^*$

**Proof $(ii)$** Results that

$$\lvert F(f) \rvert \le \int_0^1 \lvert xf(x) \rvert \;d\nu\le\int_0^1\lvert f(x)\rvert\;d\nu=\lVert f \rVert_1\quad\forall f\in L^1(X),$$ then $F\in\left(L^1(X)\right)^*$.

> $(iii)$ There is no $g\in L^\infty (X)$ for which we have that $$F(f)=\int_0^1 fg\;d\nu\quad\forall f\in L^1(X)$$

> **Question.** Are points $(i)$ and $(ii)$ correct? I can't solve point $(iii)$, could someone give me a suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: @Ruy Thanks for the observation, but I would also like to solve the exercise proposed in the post.

Comment: A better counter example is $\nu(E)=\infty$ iff $E$ is non-empty.  Then $L^\infty$ consists of all bounded measure functions, while $L^1=\{0\}$.

Comment: Ok, but I am not sure (iii) is true.  Why can't you take $g(x)=x$?

Comment: yes... unless I'm crazy, $(x\mapsto x)\in L^\infty(X)$ and $F$ is defined so that this works!

Comment: But is $g(x)=x$ $\mathcal A$-measurable?

Comment: Related issue: In part (i), you need to show that $x\mapsto xf(x)$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Comment: @JohnDawkins thanks for your interest, just give me some suggestions about what I have already done? Is point three true or not?

Comment: @JohnDawkins, good point, I guess it is not measurable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point (iii) is indeed true.  To see why suppose by contradiction that $g$ exists.  Fixing $x_0$ in $[0,1]$, take $f =
1_{\{x_0\}}$, namely the characteristic function of the singleton $\{x_0\}$, and note that
$$
  F(f) = \int_0^1fg\,d\nu = f(x_0)g(x_0)\nu (\{x_0\}) = g(x_0),
  $$
but at the same time
$$
  F(f) = \int_0^1xf(x)\,d\nu (x) = x_0f(x_0)\nu (\{x_0\}) =x_0.
  $$
Consequently we must have $g(x)=x$, for every $x$, a contradiction, because this is not an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable
function.  The reason is, e.g. that
$$
  g^{-1}(1/2,\infty ) = (1/2, 1],
  $$
which is not countable nor co-countable, hence not an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable subset.

Comment: Thank you. Are the points $(i)$ and $(ii)$ correct?

Comment: Yes, they look good to me!